# keras: reshape a tensor with None dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor

Suppose I have a tensor with the shape of `(None, a, b*c)`, and I want to reshape it to get the shape of `(None, a, b, c)`. Any idea I could do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your tensor is named `t` and of shape `(None, a, b*c)`, you can do the following:

```
 x_reshaped = tf.reshape(t, [-1, a, b, c])
```